# Can I concatenate a single quotation to a Swift String without the backslash

Tags: sql, swift, string

Trying to build up and bind an SQL query in swift.

```
var fieldnames = ""
var placeholders = ""

for key in keys {
    // build up fieldnames
    fieldnames = fieldnames + "'" + key + "'"
}
```

I end up with a string with backslashes in it like:

"INSERT INTO FormData (\'field\', \'field\', \'field\') VALUES ( Value, Value, Value)"

this causes the SQL statement to fail it doesn't like the backslashes. 
Is there anyway to avoid them?

Comment: Add `print(fieldnames)` to your code, and you'll see that the string does **not** contain any backslashes ...

Comment: Neither it does.. good spot, the query must be incorrect